# Parse not displaying all data in tables

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

I have created a simple Swift application that pulls data from a parse.com database and displays it in a `UITableView`.

The app works ok but it's only displaying 100 items from the table [there is currently 400 items on the list]. The app has a search bar and if I search for an item that is outside this initial list of 100 the item is displayed but I'm unable to see it via simply scrolling.

Is this an issue with parse.com or with my code [do I need to implement some sort of loop to continually grab data? etc]

Comment: I think Parse has a default value of 100 for queries. You can set that to a higher number.

Comment: Let me ask this is response to rdelmar's statement. Are you fetching all of the data as the view loads, and you are searching from an array of those items, or are you fetching the item as the user begins their search?

Comment: I am loading all the data as the page loads. I see I can just set 'self.pagination = true' and then list 'self.objects per page =1000' and that does work.. however this seems like a bit of a hack. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request it with fiddler and see what comes back.

You can use the limit and skip parameters for pagination. limit defaults to 100, but anything from 1 to 1000 is a valid limit.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'limit=200' \
  --data-urlencode 'skip=400' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

Try Limit and Skip from the reference page.
https://parse.com/docs/rest